# Cufon not working in Firefox or Chrome, just IE

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, cufon

This page wrapper was created last year and it worked fine in IE/Firefox/Chrome.  However, the top navigation looks correct in IE, but is not pulling in the correct code in Firefox nor Chrome.  It should be looking for the font Effra, but instead is showing Arial, which is in the css.

The nav font looks incorrect here: http://trips.eastwest.org/site/TR?fr_id=1170&pg=pfind

And it should look like the nav here: www.eastwest.org

Any insight would be great!  Thanks!
Chelsea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with my worpress site. The problem might be empty stylesheet files... search for tags that look like  in your html source or just search for href="" until you find the guilty stylesheet. Also check out the last question on https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ.